# How to secure javascript array from single quotation ' or double quotation "

Tags: javascript, arrays, sql-server, loaddata

I keep some messages in my database and when I want to use them in my application, I load them into an array first and after that, I use my array wherever it's needed. 
below is my table:

```
Id  | Message  
-------------------------------
1   | Hello, It's Jack
-------------------------------
2   | Hello, My name is "Jack"
```

I use below code to retrieve data from my database and fill my array:

```
//I have created this function to get data from database  
getResult("select * from Messages" , function(result){
    var arr = [];
    eval("arr=" + result);
});
```

in this case, my array would be as below:

```
[{Id:'1' , Message:'Hello, It's Jack'} ,
 {Id:'2' , Message:'Hello, My name is "Jack"'}]
```

which is not a valid javascript array due to an inappropriate occurrence of a single quotation in the first message. Obviously, if I use double quotations instead of a single quotation to define my array I might have the same problem with the second message.

How can I secure my array from entered single or double quotations characters in my database?

Comment: `console.log` result and please show how is that comming

Comment: [{IdRemark:'1' , Text:'Hello, It's Jack'  },{IdRemark:'2' , Text:'Hello, My name is "Jack"'  }]

Comment: You can try looping the `result` using `forEach` and push each of the value inside the local array. In that case i think it will automatically add escape character

Comment: you can use query like this,  `SELECT Id, Replace( Replace(Message, '''', '\''') , '"', '\"') AS Message`

Comment: Why do you `eval` the result from the table at all? You should just be using the value straight up - the *content* would be correct. Well, aside from the fact that you seem to wrap the content in extra single quotes but that's a problem caused by using `eval`, it shouldn't be there normally

Comment: If I don't use eval arr will be known as a string, not an array.